# slow live search on the page (MySQL InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, sql-like

There is a live search on my page. When sending a request to the server, filtering and sorting parameters are accepted (developer, publisher, genre, time, etc.). The problem is that its execution takes a fairly large amount of time, and since the script is triggered with each character entered by the user, this cannot but catch the eye. If you omit other parameters when searching and take, for example, a developer, you will get this query (the execution time is about 0.14 seconds, but when typing in the form, of course, it works slower):

```
SELECT  games.id AS id
    FROM  games
    LEFT JOIN  games_titles  ON games.id=games_titles.game_id
    WHERE  games_titles.lang=1
      AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT  1
            FROM  games_devs
            WHERE  games_devs.game_id=games.id
              AND  games_devs.dev LIKE 'de%'
                  )
    ORDER BY  games.rating DESC
    LIMIT  6
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table        | type   | possible_keys      | key           | key_len | ref              | rows  | Extra                              |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | games        | index  | PRIMARY            | rating_index  | 8       | NULL             | 1     | Using index                        |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2>  | eq_ref | distinct_key       | distinct_key  | 4       | func             | 1     | Using where                        |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | games_titles | ref    | game_id_index,lang | game_id_index | 4       | test_db.games.id | 1     | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | games_devs   | range  | PRIMARY,dev        | dev           | 452     | NULL             | 49994 | Using where; Using index           |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

Profiling:

```
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 1  | Starting               | 103 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 2  | Checking Permissions   |  16 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 3  | Opening Tables         |  32 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 4  | After Opening Tables   |  11 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 5  | System Lock            |  11 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 6  | Table Lock             |  25 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 7  | Init                   |  48 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 8  | Optimizing             |  50 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 9  | Statistics             | 145 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 10 | Preparing              |  92 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 11 | Sorting Result         |  23 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 12 | Executing              |  46 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 13 | Query End              |  14 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 14 | Removing Tmp Table     |  13 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 15 | Query End              |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 16 | Commit                 |  11 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 17 | Closing Tables         |  10 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 18 | Unlocking Tables       |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 19 | Closing Tables         |  15 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 20 | Starting Cleanup       |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 21 | Freeing Items          |  19 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 22 | Updating Status        |  73 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 23 | Reset For Next Command |  19 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
```

Since I have pagination on the site, I need to get the number of all entries so that I can go to the last page. But in this case, performance suffers much more (1.97 seconds when searching on the page):

```
SELECT games.id AS id FROM games LEFT JOIN games_titles ON games.id=games_titles.game_id WHERE games_titles.lang=1 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM games_devs WHERE games_devs.game_id=games.id AND games_devs.dev LIKE 'de%') ORDER BY games.rating
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table        | type   | possible_keys      | key           | key_len | ref              | rows  | Extra                              |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | games        | index  | PRIMARY            | rating_index  | 8       | NULL             | 99889 | Using index                        |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2>  | eq_ref | distinct_key       | distinct_key  | 4       | func             | 1     | Using where                        |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | games_titles | ref    | game_id_index,lang | game_id_index | 4       | test_db.games.id | 1     | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | games_devs   | range  | PRIMARY,dev        | dev           | 452     | NULL             | 49994 | Using where; Using index           |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------+--------------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

Profiling:

```
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 1  | Starting               | 150 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 2  | Checking Permissions   |  19 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 3  | Opening Tables         |  30 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 4  | After Opening Tables   |  12 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 5  | System Lock            |  11 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 6  | Table Lock             |  13 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 7  | Init                   |  57 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 8  | Optimizing             |  49 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 9  | Statistics             | 142 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 10 | Preparing              |  93 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 11 | Sorting Result         |  22 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 12 | Executing              |  21 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 13 | Sending Data           | 182 ms |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 14 | End Of Update Loop     |  28 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 15 | Removing Tmp Table     | 790 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 16 | End Of Update Loop     |  15 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 17 | Query End              |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 18 | Commit                 |  11 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 19 | Closing Tables         |  10 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 20 | Unlocking Tables       |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 21 | Closing Tables         |  17 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 22 | Starting Cleanup       |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 23 | Freeing Items          |  19 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 24 | Updating Status        |  75 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 25 | Reset For Next Command |  18 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE games ( 
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  rating double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  date date DEFAULT NULL, 
  date_type int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
  img varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL, 
  img_type int(10) NOT NULL, 
  url varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
  KEY rating_index (`rating`) USING BTREE, 
  KEY date_index (`date`) USING BTREE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=326678 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci 

CREATE TABLE games_titles ( 
  game_id int(50) NOT NULL, 
  title varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL, 
  lang int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
  KEY game_id_index (`game_id`) USING BTREE, 
  KEY lang (`lang`,`title`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci 

CREATE TABLE games_devs ( 
  game_id int(50) NOT NULL, 
  dev varchar(150) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`game_id`,`dev`), 
  KEY dev (`dev`,`game_id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

The request is also checked by language, because the site is multilingual. But I decided to omit these details, because the main load here is still from the search itself. I haven't put the index on the "dev" field yet, everything is set for the rest. You can see the structure of the tables above.

Can you tell me how I can improve search performance or what alternative to the LIKE operator can you offer? I have heard that many people do not recommend using it. Now in the "dev" table, the entries have the form "dev_1", "dev_2", etc. If you enter the letter "p" into the form, the script is triggered for about 10 milliseconds, with the letter "d", of course, bypassing all options takes longer. Of course, I understand that there will be much more variety in writing in real production, but still what is the best solution here? During pagination, the search time will increase with each new page (logically, because the MySQL algorithm needs to generate a new data set, but make an indent from the initial position), and I'm afraid it will take a long time, so now search optimization is my main goal.

Comment: Is it always "de%"?  How many rows in each table -- `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'game%';;`

Answer (score 0):

A few things are worth mentioning about this.

1. Progressive autocompleting search in the style you describe is a good idea; it gives a nice user experience and helps people find what they seek quickly.
2. `column LIKE '%searchterm%'` with a leading `%` is a notorious query performance antipattern. Avoid it.
3. It's a good idea, in your web page's Javascript code, to avoid sending a new search request with every single keystroke. You'll be better off if you write some Javascript to send the accumulated search data (typed by the user) a fixed amount of time after the last keystroke. So, for example, if I'm typing quickly, I can type in the word "optimization" before you send the word. But if I hesitate after "optimi" you'll send that.  A couple of hundred milliseconds is a good delay, but you can experiment with it.

   This cuts down on the server search burden, and it avoids a too-busy user experience.  (For what it's worth the [remote datasource](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) code in the [jQueryUI autocomplete widget](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) has this timing logic built in; they did a nice job of working out the various details.)
4. Correlated (dependent) subqueries are worth avoiding.

   Take this query from your example.

   ```sql
   SELECT games.id AS id
      FROM games
      LEFT JOIN games_titles ON games.id=games_titles.game_id
     WHERE games_titles.lang=1
       AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 
                    FROM games_devs
                    WHERE games_devs.game_id=games.id
                      AND games_devs.dev LIKE 'de%'
                 )
    ORDER BY games.rating DESC LIMIT 6
   ```

   If you refactor it like this it will be faster. JOIN with MAX gets you the same filtering behavior as WHERE EXISTS.

   ```sql
   SELECT games.id AS id
      FROM games
      JOIN ( SELECT MAX(game_id) game_id
               FROM games_devs
              WHERE dev LIKE 'de%
           ) AS does_dev_exist  
                ON does_dev_exist.game_id = games.id
     WHERE games_titles.lang=1
    ORDER BY games.rating DESC LIMIT 6
   ```

   This index will help accelerate the refined subquery.

   ```sql
   CREATE INDEX dev_game_id ON games_devs(dev, game_id);
   ```
5. Tables generally need multicolumn indexes that match the queries you use. Each subquery -- each line of EXPLAIN -- can in MySQL only use one index.

   The indexes you need aren't knowable except with the precise queries you use. This particular index will help your games_titles lookup in your sample query.

   ```sql
   CREATE INDEX lang_game_id ON games_titles(lang, game_id);
   ```
6. To efficiently get a total (nonpaginated) result set count do SELECT COUNT(*) and skip the ORDER BY operation. Always skip ORDER BY unless you know you need it. Better yet, if you can figure out how to avoid needing the total result set count in your autocompletion UI, do that instead.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I accidentally wrote an old table structure (the question is updated). Thank you, yes, I use indexes for many-to-many optimization. Should I leave the current option or will it be possible to speed up the request with "JOIN"? And yes, you are right about the delay before sending data to the server, I was just planning to implement this function, because with fast typing, a fairly large load is created.

Comment: I have slightly supplemented the request you proposed: 

`SELECT games.id AS id FROM games JOIN (SELECT MAX(game_id) game_id FROM games_devs WHERE dev LIKE 'de%') AS does_dev_exist ON does_dev_exist.game_id = games.id JOIN games_titles ON games.id=games_titles.game_id WHERE games_titles.lang=1 ORDER BY games.rating DESC LIMIT 6`

the execution time is 0.07 seconds. The last option is 0.09 seconds. I will test at higher values, in any case, thanks a lot for the advice. I will not close the question yet

Comment: Do we need any other indexes when getting data from the "genres" table? (In the loop, I go through all the entries and output their genre, make a "JOIN" to their list): `SELECT genres.title AS title, genres.id AS id FROM games_genres LEFT JOIN genres ON games_genres.genre_id=genres.id WHERE games_genres.game_id = ? AND genres.lang = ?`